# Asp.NET Identity setting persistent cookie to expire after specific time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity, setcookie

I have written a following code like below to refresh user roles after they subscribed to my website like following:

```
private void RefreshUserRoles()
{
    var AuthenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    var Identity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);

    Identity.RemoveClaim(Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role));
    Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Subscriber"));

    AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
        new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity), 
        new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true}
    );
}
```

Please note this line of code:

```
AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(
    new ClaimsPrincipal(Identity), 
    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true}
    );
```

After user comes back to my website I set the cookie to be persistent, but I forgot to set the expiration for this cookie. I should set this cookie to last for 30 minutes, after which user should be asked to re-log onto the system.

Since some users never re-log on website, this leaves me with an issue, now I need to reset all users cookies in their browsers when they access the website and change their role if they cancelled the subscription. I noticed some users cancelled their subscription and never relogged but yet they still are able to use features on my website...

So my questions are:

1. How to set expiration of cookie to 30 minutes after which user will be asked to re-log onto the system.
2. How to Setup to re-check users cookies if they haven't expired in a long time so that I can reset their cookies to regular user if they cancelled subscription?

Comment: Are you certain that it's the cookie, and not checking for authentication before letting them access those features?

Comment: @BillRuhl Yes 100% , I set the check upon login , checking status of subscription profile on paypal whether it's active, suspended or cancelled... But the problem is, I found out that some users never logged out from app (there are many), and this cookie was left on their browser never to expire, and they cancelled their subscription and if they never re-log, their subscription on my website basically never expires...

Comment: I dunno if it's somehow possible to force through the mvc application to force everyones cookies to expire after they accessed to the  website... That would solve my issue immediately

Comment: Possibly to set cookies expiration to expire when browser session ends ... But I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: In some of my MVC apps you set the validation interval a.k.a. timeout in the start up class. There should be a configureAuth method that you pass CookieAuthenticationOptions. One of the options is "Provider" which you assign a new "CookieAuthenticationProvider" which has the "validateInterval" property and set that equal to a TimeSpan

Comment: @BillRuhl Could you show me a practical example of this so that I can have a better insight please ? =)

Comment: @BillRuhl A yes I see it, I've set it in my app as well, mine just has set LoginPath and AuthenticationType though

Comment: @BillRuhl I can't find the validateInterval property, I only found ValidateIdentity ? \

Comment: I'll post the  whole method, one sec...

Comment: @BillRuhl okay thx alot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the ConfigureAuth method I was talking about:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Controller/Action"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
}
```

That's how I have it set and it works for me.

Comment: thanks alot, I just can't seem to figure out what are the classes ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser? I don't seem to have these in my appication since I made an empty mvc project?

Comment: using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;.....these are the the usings at the top of my start up class

Comment: I seem to have all of these references except Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google, not sure which package is this ?

Comment: You don't need it unless your going to let users authenticate with their Google+ account

Comment: Okay I installed this one, could you please check to which class does ur project references to for these classses: ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationDbContext I seem to lack these in my project?

Comment: no , then I will exclude, could you check references for these classes above i mentioned?

Comment: UserManager is from Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll, v2.0.0.0 others are defined in IdentityConfig.cs

Comment: what is this         app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); 

And why is it set to 5 minutes? =)

Comment: That is used for two factor auth...so when user logs on they are sent a text message with a code. The page that they are redirected to that asks for the code gets a cookie that is only good for five minutes. Unless your going to use a two factor system you do need it.

Comment: amazing thx!! =) So basically what this OnValidateIdentity does is checks user's browser to see if it has cookies that are longer than xx minutes or xx hours , if they are older than the set up time span, he is forced to relog, no ?

Comment: is that a yes to my previous question ? XD

Comment: Does this applies for the users that were logged in before I brought in this security feature? =)